# Works on codepen not on site, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys my code is working fine on codepen but not on my site. Can you tell me why? I have Jquery 1.11.1 included.

It behaves like the jquery was not recognized...

Here's my codepen, site and the function:

http://codepen.io/Nikolaus91/pen/azgLJG

http://178.62.215.130/LAMBRE/NewApp/subpages/kosmetykaPielegnacyjna/3.ProductPage.html#

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var topis = $('.trigger_opis');
    var opis = $('#opis');
    var tskl = $('.trigger_skl');
    var skl = $('#sklaktywne');
    var tcos = $('.trigger_dzial');
    var cos = $('#dzialanie');
    var tbadania = $('.trigger_badania');
    var badania = $('#badania');
    var all = $('.describ');
    var all3 = $('.marker');

    all3.slideUp(10);
    console.log(all3);
    topis.click(function (e) {
        all.fadeOut(500);
        e.preventDefault();
        opis.delay(100).fadeIn(2000);
console.log(opis)
    });
    tskl.click(function (e) {
        all.fadeOut(200);
        e.preventDefault();
        skl.delay(100).fadeIn(2000);

    });
    tcos.click(function (e) {
        all.fadeOut(200);
        e.preventDefault();
        cos.delay(100).fadeIn(2000);

    });
    tbadania.click(function (e) {
        all.fadeOut(200);
        e.preventDefault();
        badania.delay(100).fadeIn(2000);

    });


});
```

Comment: Are you sure you included jQuery in your page? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` (Goes in `<head>`)

Comment: Check that you have properly specify the path for jquery into   your site or else try 
jquery cdn link

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Your page throws errors...try fixing those before posting questions for us to debug your site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in timing and order of code execution. Somehow pasting the code at the begining of my script.js solved it.

Comment: Next time please try not to ask a question before you have tried everything. Questions like these are not applicable to anyone else, and all they do is waste people's time.

Comment: If I knew that could be issue I would try this, I did by mistake and it'w worked, wasn't planned. That's why I asked a question